# using "the" article in; "the Xs that exisit in the top Xs"

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I have a sentence like the following:

```
From the 400 websites, we exclude the websites that exist in the top websites list
```

Is using `the` before the first mention of `websites` correct? I can not decide whether this is a specific or general, and hence I am unable to decide whther to use `the` or not.

Comment: If you mentioned a particular set of 400 websites before this sentence, then "the" indicates the reference and is obligatory. This sentence seems a little confusing with its mention of "the top websites list" - some more context might be helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to a **specific** set of 400 websites - for instance, if you've already talked about how they were found/selected - then you need a definite article. If you're referring to an as-yet **unspecified** set of 400 websites, then no article. Though given the context I would expect you to have a specific set of websites.